# Self-study. Hypothesis testing and confidence interval

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

Given following porblem.

[image]

I have to ask this question because there is no detailed solution (only yes/no).

So my approach.

From given CI I can create following system of equations: $\begin{cases} \bar{X_n} - q_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \sigma = -2 \\ \bar{X_n} + q_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \sigma = 3 \end{cases}$,

$q_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} = 2.576$. Solving this system gives us $\bar{X_n} \approx .5$ and $\sigma \approx 0.97$

Next step is to find RR for $H_0$ which is RR={$|\bar{X_n}| > c$}, so $P(|\bar{X_n}| > c) = 0.01$, then I have (1) $P(\bar{X_n} < -c)=(P(Z< \frac{3-c}{\sigma}) = 0.005$ and (2)$P(\bar{X_n} > c)=P(Z > \frac{c+3}{\sigma}) = 0.005$
Then from (1) equation I got $c \approx -2.5$ and so $\bar{X_n} < 2.5$, from (2) $c\approx -0.5$ and so $\bar{X_n} > -.5$. So RR={$-.5 \leq \bar{X_n} \leq 2.5$}, given fact that $\bar{X_n} \approx .5$ belongs to RR $H_0$ should be rejected.

Does it make sense, is my solution valid?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A hint: think carefully about just what a "99% confidence interval" means.

Comment: Thank you for reply. CI is interval where probability that my estimator belongs to this inteval is 0.99. I'm sure that there is much more straightforward way to solve it, I just wanted to be sure that my reasoning is also correct.

Comment: @EdM: I know that it is possible to answer just by intuition, that $H_0$ is quite far from 99% CI but still I wanted to have rigorous math verification. And I want to check if this is correct.

Comment: Your understanding is close but not quite right. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Meaning_and_interpretation). If you calculate 99% CI for _multiple different samples_ from a population, then in _99% of the samples_ the true value will be somewhere within those CI. In frequentist statistics, the true value is taken to be fixed, if unknown, and it either is or is not within the CI for your sample. There is _not_ a 99% probability that the CI _from your sample_ contains the true value. So now, when do you reject a null hypothesis "at the .01 significance level"?

Comment: @EdM: Thank you for your time. Again, there is no randomicity in this problem, we are given interval and some value, and we must answer whether value belongs to interval or not.  But my approach with RR -- is it wrong or is it redundant?

Comment: I think that the way you have written the formula for RR ("rejection region"), it is for a null hypothesis that $\bar X=0$. I think that the point of this question is to get at just how a test of an hypothesis at some significance level and a set of CI for the complementary probability correspond logically. The calculations (even if they were correct) would then be redundant.

Comment: @EdM: Thx, it seems that I'm even wron with RR... What is correct RR, $|\bar{X_n} + 3| > c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, two methods can be used to explore the connection between
a t confidence interval and a t test.

**Method 1:** Confidence interval defined in terms of testing.

For normal data, a 99% t confidence interval (CI) can be defined
as an interval of values $\mu_0$ which would not be rejected in a
test of $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$ against $H_0: \mu \ne \mu_0.$

For your specific example, $\mu_0 = -3$ is not contained in the CI, so
when you test $H_0: \mu = -3$ against $H_0: \mu \ne -3,$ you will reject $H_0.$

**Method 2:** Deduce $\bar X$ and $S$ from the confidence interval and use the results to do a t test. This method works, provided that you know it's a t confidence interval and you know $n$ and the confidence level.

A 99% CI for normal mean $\mu$ is of the form $\bar X \pm t^*S/\sqrt{n},$
where $t^*$ cuts probability $0.005$ from the upper tail of Student's t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.
So you know $\bar X$ is as the center of the CI $(-2,3),$ which is $\bar X = (-2+3)/2 = 0.5.$

If $n = 20,$ then DF $= 19$ and $t^*= 2.861$ from printed tables of t distributions or by using software such as R:

```
qt(.995, 19)
[1] 2.860935
```

Then, half of the length $5$ of the CI (sometimes called the margin of error) is $2.5 = 2.861\,S/\sqrt{20},$
which you could solve to find the sample standard deviation $S.$

Finally, knowing $\bar X, S,$ and $n$ you could find the t statistic
$T = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}},$ and compare it with the critical values $\pm c = \pm 2.861$ to decide whether to reject $H_0.$

In this case, we don't know $n.$ I used $n = 20$ just to show an example where $n$ *is* known. In your case, only Method 1 is available.

*Note:* Suppose you had $n = 20$ observations as shown below, randomly sampled from a normal distribution with $\mu = -0.5, \sigma = 2.$
Then the procedure `t.test` in R can be used to test $H_0: \mu=-3$ against $H_a: \mu \ne -3$ at the 1% level and to give a 99% confidence interval for $\mu.$

In this particular case, the 99% CI is $(-2.53,  1.12),$ which does not contain $\mu_0 = -3,$ and a test of $H_0: \mu = -3$ against $H_a: \mu \ne -3$ has P-value $0.002 < 1\%,$ and so is rejected at the 1% level of significance.

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rnorm(20, -.5, 2)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-6.5775 -2.3287 -0.3243 -0.7047  1.3334  3.1001 
sd(x)
[1] 2.852494
t.test(x, mu=-3, conf.lev=.99)

    One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 3.5985, df = 19, p-value = 0.001915
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to -3
99 percent confidence interval:
 -2.529546  1.120074
sample estimates:
mean of x 
-0.704736
```